# Generate variables in for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate references to spinners and then create function .on event for all the spinners. Can I do this with a for loop since I have access to the number of times I need to repeat the code. Here is the original code:

```
var $changedInput0 = $("#mySpinnerID0");
        $changedInput0.on("input", function (event) {
            console.log("Input" + $changedInput0.val() + "counter" + slugs );
            var slug = slugs[0];
            link = "{% url 'core:addtocartproduct' 'aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz' 1 %}" 
            var link = link.replace("aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz", slug)
            var link = link.replace("/1",'/'+$changedInput0.val())
            window.location.href = link
        })     
var $changedInput1 = $("#mySpinnerID1");
        $changedInput1.on("input", function (event) {
            var slug = slugs[1];
            link = "{% url 'core:addtocartproduct' 'aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz' 1 %}" 
            var link = link.replace("aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz", slug)
            var link = link.replace("/1",'/'+$changedInput1.val())
            window.location.href = link
        })   
var $changedInput2 = $("#mySpinnerID2");
        $changedInput2.on("input", function (event) {
            var slug = slugs[2];
            link = "{% url 'core:addtocartproduct' 'aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz' 1 %}" 
            var link = link.replace("aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz", slug)
            var link = link.replace("/1",'/'+$changedInput2.val())
            window.location.href = link
        })     
var $changedInput3 = $("#mySpinnerID3");
        $changedInput3.on("input", function (event) {
            var slug = slugs[3];
            link = "{% url 'core:addtocartproduct' 'aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz' 1 %}" 
            var link = link.replace("aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz", slug)
            var link = link.replace("/1",'/'+$changedInput3.val())
            window.location.href = link
        })
```

Moreover, below is the for loop implementation which does not work. Since it is evaluated to be the maximum of the loop variable 3 in this case.

```
var k ='spin';
    for (i=0; i<slugs.length; i++){
        eval('var ' + k + i + '=   $("#mySpinnerID'+i+'");');
        s=eval('spin'+i)

        eval(s).on("input", function (event) {
                var slug = slugs[i];
                link = "{% url 'core:addtocartproduct' 'aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz' 1 %}" 
                var link = link.replace("aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz", slug)
                console.log('i',i,'slug',slug)
                var link = link.replace("/1",'/'+s.val())
                // window.location.href = link
            })


    }
```

Comment: Do you particularly need to access all these variables later by these names? This would be much simpler if you didn't need to keep them for later reference, or if you could keep them in an array.

Comment: (And by "later" I mean "elsewhere in this module of your code", not in the callback function that is defined within the loop.)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use eval(), to create/execute code, it is bad practice. You are using eval to generate code via string instead of just writing the proper code out. I hope what I provided below, puts you in the proper direction.

```
function changeInput(input, slug) {
    var link = "{% url 'core:addtocartproduct' 'aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz' 1 %}";
    $(input).on("input", event =>{
        link = link.replace("aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz", slug);
        link = link.replace("/1", '/' + input.val());
        window.location.href = link;
    })
}

for(var i = 0; i < slugs.length; i++){  
    changeInput("#mySpinnerID" + i, slug[i]);
}
```

Comment: You accidentally added a quote in `$(input).on("input,`.

Comment: good catch, was supposed to be a string "input" from the provided code above. thanks @RickardElimää

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes. You're just running into the problem of a modified closure. You need to re-declare any variable values with `let` before using them inside of the closure, so you're effectively referring to a different variable each time.

```
    for (let i=0; i<slugs.length; i++){
        let index = i; // this will be captured as a different variable on each iteration
        let $changedInput = $("#mySpinnerID" + i);
        $changedInput.on("input", function (event) {
            var slug = slugs[index];
            var link = "{% url 'core:addtocartproduct' 'aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz' 1 %}" 
            link = link.replace("aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz", slug)
            link = link.replace("/1",'/'+$changedInput.val())
            window.location.href = link
        }) 
    }
```

Long answer: Consider changing your approach. It's usually best not to rely on ID values, but instead to associate data with the DOM element more directly. For example, instead of putting the index on the ID, you could put it in a data property:

```
<input class="my-spinner" data-slug-index="1" ...
```

Then, JQuery can grab that like so:

```
$('.my-spinner').on('input', function(event) {
    var $changedInput = $(this);
    var slugIndex = $changedInput.data('slug-index');
    var slug = slugs[slugIndex];
    ...
});
```

This will add the event handler to *all* the spinners without requiring a loop.

One final note: It looks like this is using some kind of template syntax to inject data into your script:

```
    link = "{% url 'core:addtocartproduct' 'aisle-aisle-object-5-oreo-chocolate-sandwich-cookies-party-size-255-oz' 1 %}"
```

You need to be really careful with this. If there's any chance that the evaluated value could have a `"` character in it, for example, that will break your script, and quite possibly your whole page. I recommend passing values like this through a JSON serializer first, to avoid script injection problems.